# Storing Servlet post requests for a minute in file for every 1 hour interval

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, httprequest

I am trying to find some options to store a post requests for a minute to a file and want to repeat same every hour. I am having around 3000 request per second, I only want to store request message for a minute it would give me around 180000 request to do analysis. But I want to do same analysis on request messages every hour.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        ServletInputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        requestMessage = gson.fromJson(reader, Request.class);

        //I am trying to print requestMessage in one file for a minute at interval of 1 hour to do analysis on it
        //(I am having around 3000 post requests per seconds)

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT);

}
```

I have tried using below code in Post method but it doesn't work properly because it will start new schedule everytime I have new request and I put same code in init() method but it gives no output.

```
service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
service.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Starting of 1 Hour time: "+new Date());
                ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

                exec.schedule(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        System.out.println("Starting of 1 minute: "+new Date());

                        while(requestMessage.getID().equals("123"))
                        {
                            try {
                            System.out.println("Printing to File: "+new Date());    Files.write(Paths.get("location/requestMessage.txt"),requestMessage, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            }
        }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.HOUR);
```

I am kind of lost here and looking for some options. 
Can this is possible by using Executors or Thread? and if not, what are the other options I can try?

Thank you!

Comment: This is not clear "for a minute at interval of 1 hour", could you please clarify?

Comment: ideally could you provide an example to clarify ?

Comment: Thank you Nicolas for reply. I have tried to explain in bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to execute a given task during 1 minute every hour, the best you can do is to schedule a main task that will be launched every one hour which will keep on doing a recursive task as long as we don't reach one minute.

```
ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
// Schedule the main task to be executed every one our
service.scheduleAtFixedRate(
    new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Get the initial time
            long initial = System.currentTimeMillis();
            // Iterate as long as the current time - initial time is less than 60 K ms (1m)
            do {
                // Here is my recursive task that I want to do during 1 minute
            } while ((System.currentTimeMillis() - initial) < 60_000L);
        }
    }, 0L, 1L, TimeUnit.HOURS
);
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you again for the response.

Comment: I have tried using structure of your code to init() method as per my usage and it worked. Added Thread.sleep(5); in do...while loop.